# Server socket in Android, Client sockect C# not sending until socket close

Tags: c#, android, sockets

I have a socket server in Android and a client Socket in C#. The socket stablish connection properly but the information is not sended until the socket is close. Ot seems that the information is in buffer and it is not sended until the resources must be released.

The server code is:

```
Socket socket = null;
DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;

try {
     serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
     MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
          info.setText("I'm waiting here: "+ serverSocket.getLocalPort());
     }
     });

     while (true) {
         socket = serverSocket.accept();
         dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
         dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        String messageFromClient = "";

        //If no message sent from client, this code will block the program
        messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readLine();

        count++;
        message += "#" + count + " from " + socket.getInetAddress()+ ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n" + "Msg from client: " + messageFromClient + "\n";

        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             msg.setText(message);
        }
        });
```

And the client code is:

```
IPAddress host = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.129");
IPEndPoint hostep = new IPEndPoint(host, 8080);
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        try
        {
        sock.Connect(hostep);
        //sock.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, true);
        }
        catch (SocketException ex) {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem connecting to host");
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            sock.Close();
            return;
        }

      try
      {

        string theMessageToSend = "Que mierda es esta";
        byte[] msg = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(theMessageToSend + "$");
        sock.Send(msg);

        //sock.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("testing %"));
    }  catch (SocketException ex) {
      Console.WriteLine("Problem sending data");
      Console.WriteLine( e.ToString());
      sock.Close();
      return;
  }
sock.Close();
```

I can not reach the line messageFromClient = dataInputStream.readLine(); in the server side until the sock.Close(); is executed in the client side.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Try sending "\n" at the end of the string ;)

Comment: What Fildor is saying is that your Android server uses the `readLine()` method to read the data. This means it won't return until either it see an end-of-line character, or the end of the stream is reached (i.e. the connection is closed).

Comment: Thank you VERY much Fildor, it works! It takes 2 days for me...